# ASP.NET MVC AJAX passing Parameters to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'SSN' of HomeController.GetCICO(string)

from this code:

```
public JsonResult GetAllCICO()
    {
        var cicos = GetCICO().ToList();
        var jsonResult = Json(new{data = cicos}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return jsonResult;
    }
```

This is the GetCICO:

```
public List<CICO> GetCICO(string SSN)
{
List<CICO> cicos = new List<CICO>();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
{
    con.ConnectionString = str;
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 180;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM source_ips WHERE ssn_or_tin = '"+SSN+"' ORDER BY dateTrans ASC";
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (sdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    CICO cico = new CICO()
                    {
                        ssn_or_tin = sdr["ssn_or_tin"] == DBNull.Value ? (double?)null : Convert.ToDouble(sdr["ssn_or_tin"]),
                        cusid = sdr["cusid"] == DBNull.Value ? (double?)null : Convert.ToDouble(sdr["cusid"]),
                        accountNo = sdr["accountNo"] == DBNull.Value ? (double?)null : Convert.ToDouble(sdr["accountNo"]),
                        dateTrans = sdr["dateTrans"].ToString(),
                        transCode = sdr["transCode"] == DBNull.Value ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(sdr["transCode"]),
                        transdescription_1 = sdr["transdescription_1"].ToString(),
                        amount = sdr["amount"] == DBNull.Value ? (double?)null : Convert.ToDouble(sdr["amount"]),
                        cashin = sdr["cashin"] == DBNull.Value ? (double?)null : Convert.ToDouble(sdr["cashin"]),
                        cashout = sdr["cashout"] == DBNull.Value ? (double?)null : Convert.ToDouble(sdr["cashout"]),
                        source = sdr["source"].ToString()
                    };
                    cicos.Add(cico);
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
return cicos;
}
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
var SSNdata = { SSN: $("#SSN").val() };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/GetCICO",
            data: SSNdata,
            dataType: "json"
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well ,which method you want to post to? I guess this is what you want.

JS:

```
url: "/Home/GetAllCICO"
```

C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAllCICO(string SSN)
{
    var cicos = GetCICO(SSN).ToList();
    var jsonResult = Json(new{data = cicos});
    return jsonResult;
}
```

Comment: is this a question or an answer?

Comment: @Joe_DM I guess he want to post to getallcico

Comment: I want to pass a paramater to my SQL Query, is there any other way of doing that instead of my current code?

Comment: @Hansmagz The key is you need get the SSN params in your method first. what is your ajax call type, get or post?

Comment: @Hansmagz I think all my code and  Laxman Gite's will work fine. update and try debug first.

Comment: @Nico im getting error: The resource cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are calling wrong Action in controller "GetCICO" you need to call "GetALLCICO" in your URL :

```
url: "/Home/GetCICO"  this is wrong URL 

Your URL should be 

url: "/Home/GetALLCICO"
```

Your Json Action should be :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetAllCICO(string SSN)
    {
        var cicos = GetCICO().ToList();
        var jsonResult = Json(new{data = cicos}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return jsonResult;
    }
```

Because you are one parameter 'SSN' in your URL :

```
var SSNdata = { SSN: $("#SSN").val() };
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Home/GetAllCICO",
        data: JSON.stringify(SSNdata),
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

According to this your controller action should be :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAllCICO(string SSN)
```

Comment: what is the value in $("#SSN").val()

Comment: The value is from an input tag, for example: 2369646

Comment: @Hansmagz did you add a [HTTPPOST] attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Hansmagz, I think that you are trying to get data with uri **"/Home/GetAllCICO"** by **HttpGet**?

If so, please try the following codes.

#### jquery

```
var SSNdata = { SSN: $("#SSN").val() };
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/GetCICO",
        data: SSNdata,
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

#### MVC Controller

```
public JsonResult GetAllCICO(SSNdata data)
{
    var cicos = GetCICO(data.SSN).ToList();
    var jsonResult = Json(new{data = cicos}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
    return jsonResult;
}
```

#### SSNdata class

```
public class SSNdata
{
     public string SSN{get;set;}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Dude $("#SSN").val() its not model it's string.

Comment: I want to pass a paramater to my SQL Query, is there any other way of doing that instead of my current code?

Comment: I don't think there are any problem on passing parameter to you Sql query with GetCICO method. The only suggestion is using `SqlParameter` instead of string concat..

Comment: @TheFORCEJB how can i do that?

Comment: You can have a look on this [article](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06) or google it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Javascript Code ::

                var ssnData="123";
                $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                                data: JSON.stringify({ 'SSNdata': ssnData }),
                                url: '@Url.Action("GetAllCICO", "Home")',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function (cicos) {
                                    //cicos is your response data
                                }
                            });
    Controller part::

            public JsonResult GetAllCICO(string SSNdata)
                    {
                        var json=Json("Here your list",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                        return json;
                    }
```